# props.route.params.name is undefined (React Native Functional Component)

Tags: javascript, react-native-navigation

I am sending an object as params. But when I try to access the params in another screen. It says undefined.

Screen 1:

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('DraggableList', {
           routes: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
           name: 'ABCD',
         });
       }}
                                      
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Screen 2:

```
  console.log('Props==============>', props.route.params);
```

Output:

[image: Output of the above image]

But when I try to access the variables of the object:

`Screen 2:`

```
  console.log('Props==============>', props.route.params.name);
```

Output:
[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually just added a '?' like this,

```
console.log('Props==============>', props.route.params?.name)
```

And it worked!
Turns out there is a slight delay for variables to reach the component and my component was accessing it before it was available.

Answer (score 1):

as you can see props ====> ABCD, it already logged params.name
and I think the problem is with type-checking,
params have no type

try this:

```
const {name} = props.route.params as {name:string}
console.log("Props=======>",name)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but it was solved. I have posted my answer!